# Uncategorized SQLException for SQL [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT

Tags: spring, spring-batch

In my spring job we are using "Steps with Tasklets"(not chunk Oriented) approach.

In table BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT, some time we have seen status="UNKNOWN" and exit_code="FAILED" for both step1 & step2

From log we are seeen below obervation,

```
"org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback;
uncategorized SQLException for SQL [UPDATE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET
SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID = ?]; SQL
state [null]; error code [0]; Transaction cannot proceed STATUS_ROLLEDBACK;
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Transaction cannot proceed
STATUS_ROLLEDBACK
```

Not sure from where we are persisting the status as "UNKNOWN"
From tasklet , we have not seen any issue, but why some time this is happening. Did any one faced this issue and resolved.?

Find below job configuration

```
<job id="myBatchJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <step id="step1">
        <tasklet ref="MyTasklet1">
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="MyTaskletListener1" />
            </listeners>
            <transaction-attributes propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        </tasklet>
        <next on="*" to="step2" />
        <next on="FAILED" to="step2" />  
    </step> 
    <step id="step2">
        <tasklet ref="MyTasklet2">
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="MyTaskletListener2" />
            </listeners>
            <transaction-attributes propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>


public class MyTaskletListener1 {
    @BeforeStep
    void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        LOG.info("Before step execution");
    }

    @AfterStep
    ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        LOG.info("After step execution");
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I am facing the same problem with our spring batch job. Did you figure out the solution for this?